# How to append to simple JSON object in a file?

Tags: python, json

My JSON resource is out and I'm trying to fill in the gaps, so bear with me, as I don't quite know the terminology here.  I'm working to update the worlds simplest JSON File in Python.

Current `a.json`:

```
{"quarters": ["Q2-2019", "Q3-2019", "Q4-2019", "Q1-2020", "Q2-2020", "Q3-2020", "Q4-2020",
              "Q1-2021"]}
```

I'm looking to append to this, with a result of

```
{"quarters": ["Q2-2019", "Q3-2019", "Q4-2019", "Q1-2020", "Q2-2020", "Q3-2020", "Q4-2020",
              "Q1-2021", "Q2-2021"]}
```

I can't seem to find a way to quickly add within the quarters "tag". I've been able to create new "tags", but that's not my intent here.

Comment: For future reference: Those "tags" are what the [JSON specification](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) calls the "name" in the name/value pairs that make up a JSON "object". In Python they are called the "key" of the key/value pairs that comprise each of the items in a dictionary (which is what JSON objects are mapped to when loaded with `json.load()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json.load()` to parse the JSON into a dictionary. Then just append to the list in the dictionary and write it back out with `json.dump`

```
import json

with open('a.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
data['quarters'].append('Q2-2021')
with open('a.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(f, data)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a["quarters"].append("new_quarter")
```

should do it.  If it isn't in JSON format already:

```
a = json.loads(a)
a["quarters"].append("new_quarter")
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, just a comment though, you say "If it isn't in JSON format already" theny you can do `json.loads(a)`. That actually *converts from text in JSON format into a deserialized data structure*. the opposite of what you imply. And also, you'd need `a = json.loads(a)`

Comment: @juanpa arrivillaga - I deserved a downvote for that typo!  Thank you for the correction!